# Let's reopen this Dropbox question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, answered-questions

This Dropbox question was never really off-topic (though its title is a bit confusing):

- [WINE and items in notification area](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184124/wine-and-items-in-notification-area)

The best answer to this question is to explain that Dropbox exists natively for Ubuntu, and that the official Ubuntu client should be run rather than attempting to install the Windows version with Wine.

And Roland Taylor has written [an excellent answer that explains just that](https://askubuntu.com/a/184568/22949).

There's no reason for this to be closed; I recommend it be reopened. Then that answer can be accepted. (And if somebody wanted to try to answer the question about how to get Dropbox working well using the Windows version in Wine, that would be perfectly on-topic too, since questions and answers about how to get Windows software to work in Wine on Ubuntu are generally considered on-topic).

Comment: Might be missing something obvious, it pretty late here :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That all question is not about Dropbox at all, if we have a look at the comments bellow the answer from Roland we can see that its about an application called Dropshots that runs using Dropbox services.

Also that issue was also solved using an updated version from Play4Linux making it less interesting to re-open it.

Comment: That makes sense. I had not noticed that, and I no longer believe we ought to reopen that question. (However, if anybody else does think we should, of course feel free to post another answer to this meta question.)